# menu bar border using asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, menubar

I'm trying to add a menu bar with border and separator between each menu name, and the menu bar should be in middle like a banner but i'm finding difficulty in doing it please help me out.
This is my code and i'm trying to achieve it without CSS.
thanks

```
  <div id="header">
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Height="25px" Orientation="Horizontal" 
        style="margin-top: 21px" Width="833px" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="Black">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="HOME" Value="HOME"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="SERVICES" Value="SERVICES">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="SERVICES1" Value="SERVICES1"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="SERVICES2" Value="SERVICES2"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="CONTACT US" Value="CONTACT US"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ABOUT US" Value="ABOUT US"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="LOGOUT" Value="LOGOUT" NavigateUrl="~/login.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>

    </asp:Menu>   
</div>
```

this is my output screen 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8968FBBEC294BC6F!128&authkey=!AOraVApo5DcsFtY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: The only way to add separators with the asp:Menu is that you add new menu item, set its selectable property to false and set a separator image in the SeparatorImageUrl property. That's one of the reasons I like the CSS menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used css3 menu software. it works great and free! we can add menu icons too.
Just copy paste the generated code + css file to the root folder and you're done.
[here is the link](http://css3menu.com/)